# Upgrade Google-Maps API from V2 to V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to convert Google Maps API V2 into V3 but I cannot get it to work, I been trying for 3 days now and it's not working :-(

If someone can please tell me how to do this correctly I would be ***very*** thankful...

**V2 Code**

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAA4vJ90IKcF0qHxC2Cg9NjchT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQ-rtrvY-Stu0L_q-OypfOv3WnUfg" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir, getCityName, getcITIESName, getDeliveryCityName, PickState, DeliveryState, SteState, SteStateB2, theAddress1, memeaddress1, memeaddress2;

function initialize() {

geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
gDir = new GDirections();
GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {
var drivingDistanceMiles = (gDir.getDistance().meters / 1609.344).toFixed(0);//for 0 decial place
var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
//theAddress1 = location1.address
getCityName = location1.address.split(",")
memeaddress1 = getCityName[0] + ',' + getCityName[1];

getcITIESName = location2.address.split(",");
memeaddress2 = getcITIESName[0] + ',' + getcITIESName[1].substr(0,3);
SteState = document.getElementById('selFromState').options[document.getElementById('selFromState').options.selectedIndex].value;
SteStateB2 = document.getElementById('selToState').options[document.getElementById('selToState').options.selectedIndex].value;
if (document.getElementById("inputString").value + ', ' + SteState == memeaddress1)
{
}
else
{
  doItagain=confirm('Cannot find the Pickup City!\n\nDid you mean: ' + location1.address + ' ?' + '\n\nPress OK to Change\nCancel to keep the City and State you entered!\n\n\n');
  if(doItagain){
getCityName[1] = (getCityName[1]).replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
var showonlythefirst2ltrspickup = getCityName[1].substr(0,2) 
document.getElementById("inputString").value = getCityName[0]
document.getElementById("selFromState").value = showonlythefirst2ltrspickup;
showLocation()
  }

  else

// Just end and exit function
window.alert('Please Note you must enter the miles manually!')
document.getElementById("txtMiles").value = "0";
//}
}
if (document.getElementById("inputString2").value + ', ' + SteStateB2 == memeaddress2)
{
document.getElementById("txtMiles").value = drivingDistanceMiles;
checkemptyB2();
}
else
{
  doIt=confirm('Cannot find the Delivery City!\n\nDid you mean: ' + location2.address + ' ?' + '\n\nPress OK to Change\nCancel to keep the City and State you entered!\n\n\n');
  if(doIt){
getcITIESName[1] = (getcITIESName[1]).replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
var showonlythefirst2ltrs = getcITIESName[1].substr(0,2) 
document.getElementById("inputString2").value = getcITIESName[0]
document.getElementById("selToState").value = showonlythefirst2ltrs;

showLocation()
  }

  else

// Just end and exit function
window.alert('Please Note you must enter the miles manually!')
document.getElementById("txtMiles").value = "0";
}
});
}

function showLocation() {
checkemptyB2();
//geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
//gDir = new GDirections();
//alert("here is the pickup address:" + document.getElementById("inputString2").value + ',' + document.getElementById("selToState").value)
geocoder.getLocations(document.getElementById("inputString").value + ',' + document.getElementById("selFromState").value, function (response) {
if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
{
alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the pickup address");
}
else
{
location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
geocoder.getLocations(document.getElementById("inputString2").value + ',' + document.getElementById("selToState").value, function (response) {
if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
{
alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the delivery address");
}
else
{
location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: 

response.Placemark[0].address};
gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' to: ' + location2.address);
}
});
}
});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changedelivery() {
  doIt=confirm('do you wish to proceed?');
  if(doIt){
document.getElementById("inputString2").value = getcITIESName[0]
document.getElementById("selToState").value = SteStateB2
  }
  else{
// Just end and exit function
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder,location1,location2,gDir,getCityName,getcITIESName,getDeliveryCityName,PickState,DeliveryState,SteState,SteStateB2,theAddress1,memeaddress1,memeaddress2;

function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
gDir = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
google.maps.Event.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {
var drivingDistanceMiles = (gDir.getDistance().meters / 1609.344).toFixed(0);//for 0 decial place
var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;

getCityName = location1.address.split(",")
memeaddress1 = getCityName[0] + ',' + getCityName[1];

getcITIESName = location2.address.split(",");
memeaddress2 = getcITIESName[0] + ',' + getcITIESName[1].substr(0,3);

SteState = document.getElementById('selFromState').options[document.getElementById('selFromState').options.selectedIndex].value;
SteStateB2 = document.getElementById('selToState').options[document.getElementById('selToState').options.selectedIndex].value;


if (document.getElementById("inputString").value + ', ' + SteState == memeaddress1)
{
}
else
{
  doItagain=confirm('Cannot find the Pickup City!\n\nDid you mean: ' + location1.address + ' ?' + '\n\nPress OK to Change\nCancel to keep the City and State you entered!\n\n\n');

if(doItagain){
getCityName[1] = (getCityName[1]).replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
var showonlythefirst2ltrspickup = getCityName[1].substr(0,2) 
document.getElementById("inputString").value = getCityName[0]
document.getElementById("selFromState").value = showonlythefirst2ltrspickup;
showLocation()
  }

else

// Just end and exit function
window.alert('Please Note you must enter the miles manually!')
document.getElementById("txtMiles").value = "0";
//}
}

if (document.getElementById("inputString2").value + ', ' + SteStateB2 == memeaddress2)
{
document.getElementById("txtMiles").value = drivingDistanceMiles;
checkemptyB2();
}

else

{
  doIt=confirm('Cannot find the Delivery City!\n\nDid you mean: ' + location2.address + ' ?' + '\n\nPress OK to Change\nCancel to keep the City and State you entered!\n\n\n');

if(doIt){
getcITIESName[1] = (getcITIESName[1]).replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
var showonlythefirst2ltrs = getcITIESName[1].substr(0,2) 
document.getElementById("inputString2").value = getcITIESName[0]
document.getElementById("selToState").value = showonlythefirst2ltrs;

showLocation()
  }

else

// Just end and exit function
window.alert('Please Note you must enter the miles manually!')
document.getElementById("txtMiles").value = "0";
}
});
}

function showLocation() {
checkemptyB2();
geocoder.geocode(document.getElementById("inputString").value + ',' + document.getElementById("selFromState").value, function (response) {


if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
{
alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the pickup address");
}

else

{
location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
geocoder.geocode(document.getElementById("inputString2").value + ',' + document.getElementById("selToState").value, function (response) {
if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
{
alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the delivery address");
}

else

{
location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: 

response.Placemark[0].address};
gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' to: ' + location2.address);
}
});
}
});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changedelivery() {
  doIt=confirm('do you wish to proceed?');

if(doIt){
document.getElementById("inputString2").value = getcITIESName[0]
document.getElementById("selToState").value = SteStateB2
}

else

{
// Just end and exit function
}
}
</script>
```

Thanks again for any help with this!

Comment: What code have you got so far after three days? Why don't you post it for us

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos I used this as a guide http://gabrielduque.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/upgrading-from-google-maps-api-v2-to-v3/

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos I will update the question and I will add the code with the V3 non-working code below the V2 working code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that starts with a "G" is a v2 class.  You need to replace:

- GClientGeocoder(); -> [google.maps.Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)
- GDirections();     -> [google.maps.DirectionsService & google.maps.DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

With their v3 equivalents.  They are different, see the documentation for details.

Comment: I made those changes also but I'm still getting an error on line geocoder.getLocations(document.getElementById("inputString").value + ',' + document.getElementById("selFromState").value, function (response) {  // ERROR IS: geocoder.getLocations is not a function
Source, I updated the code that I have tried so far if you can please look at it and see what I'm doing wrong please. Thank you.

Comment: But you didn't read the documentation.  The v3 Geocoder doesn't have a  getLocations method.

Comment: says: In v3, it use geocoder.geocode() instead of GClientGeocoder.getLocation() I changed that also (see code above) but it's still giving me an error. I guess I'm in over my head with this one, I will credit you for the answer and try understanding this alil better, Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it also states that the geocode method takes a GeocoderRequest object as its first argument, so to pass in an address, you need to do `geocoder.geocode({address: document.getElementById("inputString").value + ',' + document.getElementById("selFromState").value}, function(result, status) {}`